# ORA-01722: invalid number 01722. 00000 - "invalid number" *Cause: The specified number was invalid. *Action: Specify a valid number

Tags: oracle, substring

I am new to Oracle SQL Developer, and today while running this

```
select r.id, r.date,  it.group, it.comment, it.item, it.remark, r.summary,
substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'ABC')+8,7 )  as label1,
cast(substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'-')+1,3 ) as integer) as label2
from it_table it 

inner join sp_table sp on sp.id = substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'ABC')+8,7 ) and sp.label_id = cast(substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'-')+1,3 ) as integer) 
inner join sq_table sq on sq.id = sp.id
where it.date > '01-jan-2020' and it.remark like '%ABC%' and it.group= 'O'
order by sp.id, it.id;
```

it caught the error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

I think the problem lies with the extraction as in row 3 (`cast(substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'-')+1,3 ) as integer)`), where I need to convert a string into a number using `cast`.

According to [doc](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722), the error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a valid number.

So, I tried replacing:

```
cast(substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'-')+1,3 ) as integer)
```

with

```
to_number(substr (it.remark, instr(it.remark,'-')+1,3 ))
```

and even tried `to_char` but didn't work. However, the original script seems to work fine in sandbox database. I am wondering why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Update:

Sample data `it`:

```
     ID    DATE       NAME     GROUP     REMARK                              COMMENT ... 
     100   20-10-08   AABC     X         ACS LOCATION 1 - ABC IDD x105213-1    
     ​101   20-10-08   AxB      Y         MN  LOCATION 8 - ABC IDD x105244-2 
     ...
```

Sample data `sp`:

```
     ID       DATE       NAME     GROUP     label_id   
     105213   20-10-08   AABC     X         1   
     ​105244   20-10-08   AxB      Y         2
     ...
```

It turns out that the error was caused by having 2 `-` in `remark` which lead to ambiguity and I just need the second one.

New question then:

How do I extract the **last** `-` in the value to join with another value in the other column?

Comment: Have you verified that the cast is the problem - does the error go away if you remove that column expression (and the matching join condition)? The `sp.id = substr(...)` looks suspicious to me too though, if `id` is a number column, since you seem to be packing multiple bits of data into that one `remark` value. Can you include some sample data - particularly examples values for `remark`?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, you're right , it turns out that the error was caused by having 2 `-` in `remark` which lead to ambiguity and I just need the second one. I have added an example sample to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75) with `default null on conversion error`  to avoid exception and investigate the cause of the failed conversion.

*Example*

```
with dt as 
(select '001' remark from dual union all
 select '  2' from dual union all
 select 'OMG' from dual)
select substr(remark,1,3) txt,
cast (substr(remark,1,3) as INT default null on conversion error) num
from dt;

TXT        NUM
--- ----------
001          1
  2          2
OMG
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It turns out that the error was caused because there were 2 `-` in `remark` which lead to ambiguity and I just need the second one.. But thank you for your help:)